# How to temporarily disable TLS1.3 in Chrome?

Tags: tls

I need to temporarily disable the TLS 1.3 protocol leaving only TLS 1.2 for some testing purpose.
I found some procedures on Google but they didn't not work. Please give me the guidance.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include links to the things you have tried, even if they have not worked for you.

Comment: Chrome doesn't provide explicit option to choose TLS version in the UI. We need to add commandline option `-ssl-version-min=tls1.2` in the startup command. [This article explains the steps for both Chrome and Firefox](https://sites.google.com/view/a-bit-better-privacy/use-tls-1-3-and-tls-1-2#h.p_RKKua-F1UzzG).

Comment: @DeepakDevanand But that sets the *minimum* version - Ahamed wants to set the *maximum* version.

Comment: @Joseph you're right. [The list of commandline options for Chrome](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#ssl-version-max) does have `--ssl-version-max` option as well.

Comment: Thank you for your support Deepak and Joseph.